# How to place a checkMark as a character?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$("#status").html('<img src="available.png">Available');
```

Instead of checkMark picture I want a chekMark character.
Is there a way, please?

Comment: Did you even try googling? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
$("#status").html('&#10003;');
```

Comment: We are here for that! I'm glad I helped you!

Answer (score 22):

You could use [U+2713](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm) (Check Mark Symbol ✓):

```
$("#status").text("\u2713 Available");
```

Comment: `\u2705` for heavy green check-mark.

Answer (score 4):

try either of

```
&#10003;
```

`&#x2713;`

one is hex, one is decimal.  If I don't put code markers around them, you get

✓    ✓

Answer (score 3):

See this: http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=dingb

`&#10003;` or `&#10004;`

Although I must say that I think a picture is a better option: you can modify it later at any time without changing your code.

Comment: @ cegfault, I agree, but I have another reasons for charachter solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Decimal:**

```
&#10003;
```

or
**hex:**

```
&#x2713;
```

**example:** `$("#status").html('&#10003;');`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a check mark in a web font.

This question (and the answers) are now five years old.  For the sake of those coming from Google, I wanted to add another option that's become available in recent years, but is not mentioned in previous answers.

You can certainly still use unicode characters (`.html("&#10003;")` or `.text("\u2713")`, but in the past few years web fonts have become more common.  For example, material icons has a check mark:
https://material.io/icons/#ic_check

Google (who made and maintains material icons) also did a good job of explaining web fonts and how to use them here: https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/

Basically web fonts are the best of both worlds: the customization of images and the usage/dynamics of font characters. The advantages to using web fonts over unicode characters are:

- control over style (you can make your own web font character of any style, whereas unicode characters are what they are)
- use of multiple styles (you can make web fonts with numerous styles of check marks for different situations; you're not locked into one style)
- code readability (very few developers will know what `\u2713` or `&#10003` means, but `<i class="myfont">check</i>` is easy to understand
- portability: although every major browser uses a unicode font by default, there are still some computers or devices which may render with a non-unicode font by default. In fact, [wikipedia's current list of unicode fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font#List_of_Unicode_fonts) is decently long, but the supported characters vary widely between each font, and there are clear differences between how the each font is rendered by different platforms.  Including a webfont ensures that every user will see the same thing, regardless of platform or default fonts.
- More options: having an installed webfont allows you to update the style, add new icons/characters to the font, etc.  There is no way to currently do this with unicode.